# Get category name from category id laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to laravel and have two table one post table and one category table. I have only one category related to one post, so i add category id in post table.So now i want to display all post with category name.

**post table:**
id,name,category_id,status

**category Table:**
id,name

i want to dispaly like
POST NAME
CATEGORY NAME

I have two model category and post, so how can i write the eloquent relationship or give me a simple way to get the array of post with category name

Comment: Have you done any research about relatioships in Laravel ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your Post model you can write the category relationship like this:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class); // don't forget to add your full namespace
}
```

You can then do something like this...

```
$posts = Post::with('category')->get();
```

which will get all your posts with the category it belongs to.

You can then iterate over the `$posts` variable, for example, using blade...

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $post->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $post->category->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Read up further here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: @Niju You'd do yourself a favour by getting through this: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017 it's all free too! Happy coding!

Comment: i have one more issue there, when i am adding paginate its not working $posts = Post::with('category')->get()->paginate(5); and i tried in the model also

Comment: Firstly, please mark the answer as correct if it answered your question. You need to use `paginate()` instead of `get()` don't use both together.

Comment: Paginate goes in the controller, not the model. `$posts = Post::with('category')->paginate(5);`

Answer (score 6):

In your Post model:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Now it will be available to you from the Post model directly

```
$post = Post::find($id);

$category_name = $post->category->name;
```

Edit for question in comment:

There are a number of ways you can get posts by category name, for easy of use I would do this:

In category model:

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Now you have it available through the category model:

```
$category = Category::where('name', $name)->first();

$posts_collection = $category->posts()->get();
```

Comment: i want to get all the post with category name, and how to code in controller to return all these values.