# Laravel: User & Post Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Model Structure
**user.php**

```
public function inventories() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\user\inventory')->orderBY('created_at','DESC')->paginate(10);
}
```

**inventory.php**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Model\user\user')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Table Structure:**

**inventories:**

```
id
user_id
content
```

**users:**

```
id
name
email
```

How to call the `inventories->user_id` to connect in `users->id` in controller?
Example in laravel blade:

```
user_id = 1  
content = 'This is content'
```

I want is:

```
user_id = 'Name of user 1'  
content = 'This is content'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get category name from category id laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193174/get-category-name-from-category-id-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined your relations, you can use :

```
$inventories = Inventory::all();

foreach ($inventories as $inventory) {

    foreach ($inventory->users as $user) {

         echo $user->name; // show the name of user
    }

    // or to get first user :
    $user_1_name = isset($inventory->users[0]) ? $inventory->users[0]->name : '-';
}
```

Comment: i just found the answer -_- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193174/get-category-name-from-category-id-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

On your controller:

```
$inventories = Inventory::all();
```

On your blade file:

```
@foreach ($inventories as $inventory)
    {{ $inventory->users()->id }}<br/>
@endforeach
```